# Square to "diagonal" matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a set of vectors, and would like to stack them on top of each other to create diagonal entries to a matrix.

What would be an easy way to create the example_out matrix from c1 and c2?

```
c1 <- seq(1, 4)
c2 <- seq(5, 8)


example_out <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,5,2,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,7,4,0,0,0,8), nrow=5, byrow=T)
example_out
```

Comment: [`?diag`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/diag.html), plus @jaySf's trick for setting the off-by-one diagonal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a matrix out of `0`s, then fill main diagonal with `c1` and sub diagonal with `c2`.

```
example_out <- matrix(rep(0, 20), 5, 4)
diag(example_out) <- c1
diag(example_out[-1, ]) <- c2
```

***Yielding***

```
> example_out
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    5    2    0    0
[3,]    0    6    3    0
[4,]    0    0    7    4
[5,]    0    0    0    8
```

***Data***

```
c1 <- seq(1, 4)
c2 <- seq(5, 8)
```

Comment: Neat. You can also avoid the `rep` - `mat <- matrix(0, 5, 4)` will work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative approach `replace`ing entries in a `numeric` vector before casting as `matrix`

```
matrix(unlist(sapply(seq_along(c1), function(i)
    replace(rep(0, length(c1) + 1), i:(i+1), c(c1[i], c2[i])))),
    ncol = length(c1))
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    5    2    0    0
#[3,]    0    6    3    0
#[4,]    0    0    7    4
#[5,]    0    0    0    8
```

---

### Update

I was curious to see how the different methods compared in terms of performance/runtime. Here is a short `microbenchmark` analysis using two larger `vector`s `c1` and `c2`.

```
set.seed(2017)
c1 <- sample(1000)
c2 <- sample(1000)

library(microbenchmark)
library(Matrix)

res <- microbenchmark(
    method_jaySF = {
        example_out <- matrix(0, length(c1) + 1, length(c2))
        diag(example_out) <- c1
        diag(example_out[-1, ]) <- c2
    },
    method_Roland = {
        bandSparse(length(c1) + 1, length(c2), 0:-1, list(c1, c2))
    },
    method_Onyambu = {
        a = matrix(0,length(c1)+1,length(c2))
        a[row(a)==col(a)]=c1
        a[row(a)==col(a)+1]=c2
    },
    method_Gregor = {
        rbind(diag(c1), 0) + rbind(0, diag(c2))
    },
    method_Maurits = {
        matrix(unlist(sapply(seq_along(c1), function(i)
    replace(rep(0, length(c1) + 1), i:(i+1), c(c1[i], c2[i])))),
    ncol = length(c1))
    }
)
res;
#Unit: microseconds
#           expr       min       lq      mean    median         uq        max
#   method_jaySF 31894.439 37850.81  58452.41 40560.992  46224.579 208862.631
#  method_Roland   940.535  1342.32   1675.29  1457.928   1869.621   8228.287
# method_Onyambu 55033.797 66083.67 124364.44 73143.798 195886.534 274383.132
#  method_Gregor 37784.977 44049.87  69918.85 47539.793  53122.162 243774.715
# method_Maurits 14961.924 21378.77  42834.89 23536.966  27270.953 186088.146

autoplot(res)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another simple approach, augmenting two diagonal matrices with 0 rows and adding them:

```
rbind(diag(c1), 0) + rbind(0, diag(c2))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    5    2    0    0
# [3,]    0    6    3    0
# [4,]    0    0    7    4
# [5,]    0    0    0    8
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a sparse matrix. Use the Matrix package:

```
c1 <- seq(1, 4)
c2 <- seq(5, 8)

library(Matrix)
bandSparse(5, 4, 0:-1, list(c1, c2))
#5 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#            
#[1,] 1 . . .
#[2,] 5 2 . .
#[3,] . 6 3 .
#[4,] . . 7 4
#[5,] . . . 8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 a = matrix(0,length(c1)+1,length(c2))
 a[row(a)==col(a)]=c1
 a[row(a)==col(a)+1]=c2
 a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    5    2    0    0
[3,]    0    6    3    0
[4,]    0    0    7    4
[5,]    0    0    0    8
```